# PIXI import not working: Cannot find module pixi.js

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I npm installed pixi.js into a typescript project.  This line (found in many examples) does not work:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
```

I get the error "Cannot find module 'pixi.js'"

I tried this workaround and it works fine:

```
const PIXI = require('pixi.js');
```

The problem is that this loses the type information I want. Pixi has a d.ts file, so I should be getting types.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you use `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your tsconfig.json

Comment: I needed `"module": "commonjs"`

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on your entire configuration. If you only use typescript, without a bundler you can continue using the `require` option and in your `tsconfig.json` make sure you have :

`include:[]`

Pointing directly to your `pixi... d.ts` file.

If you use a bundler like webpack, it will depend on what version of PIXI you use.

Before 5.0.0, it was fairly simple and your first approach should do the trick.  A while ago I created a demo repository for the same purpose:
https://github.com/idzhurov/pixijs-game-boilerplate

In 5+ versions, everything is modular, so it is a bit more specific. 
You can try to start with the:
`import { Application } from 'pixi.js'`
 and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

@Naxos84:
If you can't use "moduleResolution": "node" try adding this to your tsconfig.json "compilerOptions"-object:

```
"paths": {
  "mini-signals": [
    "node_modules/resource-loader/typings/mini-signals.d.ts" 
  ],
   "resource-loader": [
     "node_modules/resource-loader/typings/resource-loader.d.ts"
   ],
   "pixi.js": [
     "node_modules/pixi.js/index.d.ts" 
   ],
   "*": ["*", "node_modules/*/index.d.ts", "node_modules/*/types/index.d.ts"]  
},
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
"allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,         
"baseUrl": "./",
```